# Flutter: disabling an IconButton with an asset as icon

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to disable an `IconButton` inside a `State<T>` class based on a condition. The official documentation states that in order to disable a button, the `onPressed` callback should be `null`. This makes the icon greyed-out.

This is however NOT true for icons with a custom asset. E.g. when having the following two icons

```
IconButton(
      icon: Image.asset(somePath),
      iconSize: 24,
      onPressed: condition?()=>{someCallback();}:null),
IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.settings,
      ),
      iconSize: 24,
      onPressed: condition?()=>{someCallback();}:null)
```

Then the first is grayed out but the latter is not. So how could I disable an `IconButton` with an `Image.asset` as image provider?

Answer (score 4):

Simply because `IconThemeData` can be applied on `Text` and `Icon` as their color can be changed but not on asset image, which does not have a color property.
Still, you can alter it like this

```
IconButton(
    icon: Image.asset(somePath, color: condition ? null : Colors.grey,),
    iconSize: 24,
    onPressed: condition ? () {
      someCallback();
    } : null,
),
IconButton(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.settings,
    ),
    iconSize: iconSize,
    onPressed: condition ? () {
      someCallback();
    } : null,
),
```

Comment: But you set the color of `Image.asset`, so it does have a color property, right?

Comment: Yeah, indeed. But `IconThemeData` cannot be applied to this. You have to manually set it depending on your condition as I did